# Structures in VB .NET like COBOL

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-structures, cobol

I'm converting a COBOL program to VB .NET.

Is there any way to use the structures in VB NET like COBOL does?

In example:

COBOL:

```
01 VAR1
    10  VAR11 PIC X
    10  VAR12 PIC X

MOVE 'AA' TO VAR1
```

After that VAR11 = A and VAR12 = A

Is there any way to move a string over the top header of a structure in VB NET and every member of this structure takes the 'piece' of the corresponding string?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But VB.Net (well, it's not VB specific) [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1wwdcbf.aspx) class offers a lot of functionality - you can [index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1wwdcbf.aspx#Indexes) it like an array, you can ask for [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx)s, etc.

Don't try to literally copy all aspects of the COBOL program. Look for small wins where you can write cleaner VB code.

Comment: This forum was my last hope. I expected to avoid to create a class that simulates this functions. Thanks!!!

Comment: String is charachter based -- a non-single byte encoding could mess things up. ByteArray with index mappings for data types might be a nicer approach.

Answer (score 0):

This may be red herring, but would something like:

```
Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
```

help in any way?  Group level moves are pretty much untyped byte for byte moves.  Maybe judicious use of memory moves could suffice?  Or crash the whole thing, as it'd be delicate code worthy of cement fencing.

Using this may also require judicious use of

```
VarPtr(), StrPtr(), or ObjPtr()
```

to get at pointers.